# Dovecot mail-crypt webmail can't read encrypted messages

Tags: email-server, dovecot

I'm trying to setup Dovecot with mail-crypt plugin with per-user encryption.

I have configured mail-crypt plugin as per official guide here: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_crypt_plugin/

After that I created a user and an encrypted key by running this command: doveadm -o \plugin/mail_crypt_private_password=12345 mailbox cryptokey generate -u
mail@example.org -URf

I can log in to webmail (and Dovecot) just fine, emails are getting sent and delivered. I have also checked the storage and the messages seem to be stored encrypted.

However, I can't read the emails in webmail (just headers can be seen) and in Dovecot logs I can see the following error:

failed: Private key not available: Cannot decrypt key ### Cannot decrypt key ### <8632: Password not available (FETCH RFC822.HEADER)

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

UPDATE: There seems to be an issue with mySQL query. The query I'm using (Select username as "user", password,"%w" as userdb_mail_crypt_private_password from mailbox;) seems to work just fine, when run from mysql prompt it outputs the usernames and passwords, but the error is still there (Cannot decrypt key ### Password not available).

Comment: Do web user have right to read the keys?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By web user you mean the webmail user? How it's possible to check this? Where the keys are located?

Comment: In mail plugin configuration you should set these keys, search for `mail_crypt_global_private_key` and `mail_crypt_global_public_key`

Comment: yes, but that's for the global keys, I'm trying to use per-user keys...